# Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to do Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 configuration. But I am facing sessionFactory = null in the Controller. Below are the configurations and code.
What is the mistake in this configuration?

spring-database.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- MySQL data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/personal" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/orm/Song.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="songDao" class="com.letsdo.impl.SongImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- MUST have transaction manager, using aop and aspects  -->
     <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

orm/Song/hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.letsdo.model.Song" table="song" catalog="personal">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" length="45" />
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="filePath" column="filepath"/>
        <property name="fileName" column="filename"/>
        <property name="album" column="album"/>
        <property name="title" column="title"/>
        <property name="size" column="size"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

SongDao.java

```
public interface SongDao {

    public List<String> getAllAlbums();
}
```

SongImpl.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SongImpl implements SongDao{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<String> getAllAlbums(){
        List<String> allAlbums = new ArrayList<String>();
        Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("Select DISTINCT Album from song");
        allAlbums = query.list();
        return allAlbums;

    }
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Controller: HomeController.java

```
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired private SongImpl songDao;
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePageBeforeLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,HttpSession session){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        List<String> album = songDao.getAllAlbums();
        model.addObject("albumsize",album.size());
        model.setViewName("hello");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a `<context;component-scan />` which detects the `SongImpl`, but there is no `@Autowired` so nothing is ever going to be injected.

Comment: Where should I include @Autowired?  I have it in Controller.

Comment: autowired above sessionFactory in SongImpl ....so that it will inject that bean into it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are ending up with two beans of class SongImpl - one that is defined in xml (named `songDao`), and another one annotated with @Service (named by default `songImpl`). The latter one has no SessionFactory autowired, that's why it is null.

You can find more info about it in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358825/spring-behavior-when-mixing-component-scanning-and-xml-bean-definition-for-the-s).

> If component scanning is enabled, spring will try to create a bean
>   even though a bean of that class has already been defined in the
>   spring config xml. However if the bean defined in the spring config
>   file and the auto-discovered bean have the same name, spring will not
>   create a new bean while it does component scanning.

The solution is to remove the xml version of the bean (if you don't need it), and to autowire SessionFactory in SongImpl.